# Problems with clicking on input areas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

Occassionally people will have trouble clicking on textboxes in a modal popup window on my site. This issue is not consistent and I have not been able to reproduce it, but I've had enough reports of it that I'm confident the issue exists.

Tabbing into the textbox works and *also* makes the textbox clickable again, which is very confusing to me.

I'm looking for possible reasons this could happen and things to look for.

Comment: this could be many things, browser compatibility, plugin issue, wrong jquery call, etc, I guess you can add a reference to your site or at least a code to check.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to post any code to go with this? Are the reports coming from a specific browser?

I've seen issues like this where the modal is inside a form element, but it hasn't been a problem for a long time. This sounds like an Internet Explorer "feature" to me.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there any objects flying over inputs preventing clicking.